# Required Field Validators

Tags: c#, validation

I have (3) text boxes:  txtPayRate, txtStartDate, txtFinishDate.  Next to them I have a required field validator: reqPayRate, reqStartDate, reqFinishDate.  If the text box is left blank or has the wrong format I want it to return the error message I have stated in the properties menu.  I want the txtPayRate to be a number and the date format to be mm/dd/yyyy.  I'm not sure how to write this section of code.  If I can get help on the txtPayRate and txtStartDate I can get the other.  C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it in your model and mvc will generate clientside-validation for you:

```
 public class FooModel{

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"]
        public DateTime RequestedStartDate{
             get; set;
        }

        [Required]
        public decimal RequestedPayRate{
             get; set;
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you let them type Chars ?

please use some Js validation like DatePicker

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

you can also declare the format.